# Reasoning about equation combined with inequalities

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, systems-of-equations

The given problem eventually boils down to finding the interval for $x_5$ given these facts
$\begin{equation}\begin{cases}x_2+x_4+x_5=590\\180<x_2<200\\x_4>200\\x_5>x_4\end{cases}\end{equation}, x_2, x_4,x_5\in N$.

I will show how I reason below (answer is right), but kindly advise me if there is a quicker, more straightforward way.

From line 1 in the system, we se that $x_2$ (together with $x_4$) affects $x_5$. We therefore need to find an interval for $x_2$ where the system is valid. To find the interval for $x_2$, we start with eq. on line 1 in the system using the lowest possible values for $x_4=201$ and $x_5=202$.    We get the equation

$x_{2a} + 201+202=590 \iff x_{2a} = 187$.

Since $x_4$ and $x_5$ can only increase from $x_4=201$ and $x_5=202$ that means $x_{2a}$ must decrease from 187 in order for the latest equation above to hold. We've found the interval for $x_2$, $181\leq x_2 \leq 187$. Now put $x_2=181$ and $x_2=187$ into the first eq of the system and solve the systems.

Case 1 ($x_2=181$):

$181+x_4+x_5=590 \iff x_4+x_5=409$. If we assume the lowest possible value for $x_4=201$ then (according to $x_4+x_5=409$) $x_5=208$.

Case 2 ($x_2=187$):

$187+x_4+x_5=590 \iff x_4+x_5=403$. If we assume the lowest possible value for $x_4=201$ then (according to $x_4+x_5=403$) $x_5=202$.

The interval for $x_5$ is $202\leq x_5 \leq 208$.

This is right according to the provided solution, and I thought of this solution, but I'm having some difficulty articulating why I chose to use the "lowest number" a couple of times.

Comment: It's stated nowhere, but it seems to be assumed: $x_2,x_4,x_5$ are supposed to be integers?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Correct.

Comment: Then that's right, $187$ is the largest possible of $x_2$, with only one possibility for $x_4$ and $x_5$, and all values of $x_2$ between $181$ and $187$ are possible. However, depending on where this problem comes from, it might be expected that you give all triplets $x_2,x_4,x_5$ that satisfy these constraints. There aren't many of them, you can do it by hand.

Comment: As you have stated, the minimum values of $x_4$ and $x_5$ yield the maximum possible value of $x_2$ because of the equality. Then all lower values of $x_2$ that are $>180$ are also possible because there is no upper constraint on $x_4$ and $x_5$ (the only constraint is that $x_2$ can't decrease below $181$). Then, giving all solutions is pretty straightforward: for each $x_2$, you know $x_4+x_5$, and given the constraints, only a small number of cases for $x_4$ and $x_5$.

Comment: If you want to check your answer, the number of triplets is $16$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I see only one possibility for $x_4=201$ but two for $x_5=208$, $x_5=202$. Did you mean to say "two" possibilities for $x_5$? Thanks for the heads-up about more answers, but the problem only asked for $x_5$.

Comment: For $x_2=187$, you must have $x_4=201$ and $x_5=202$: one triplet. For $x_2=186$, there is still only one solution, $x_4=201$ and $x_5=203$. Then for $x=185$, there are two solutions: $x_4=201$ and $x_5=204$ or $x_4=202$ and $x_5=203$. Likewise for the other values of $x_2$.